# Set cookie then redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

The cookie is not holding and the domain example.com cannot redirect to a.example.com when I type on the address bar. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
$(function() {
  var city = getCookie('city');
  if (city != null && city != '') {
    window.location.href = 'http://' + city + '.example.com';
  }
  $('#citygo').change(function() {
    var city = $(this).val();
    window.location.href = 'http://' + city + '.example.com';
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="citygo">
  <option value="0">Select City</option>
  <option value="amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
  <option value="newyork">New York</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
  <option value="cardiff">Cardiff</option>
</select>
```

Is it like this? It is not working. Here is the code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var cookieName = 'city';
  var cookieValue = 'city';
  var myDate = new Date();
  myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + `";domain=.example.com;path=/;expires=" + myDate;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $(function() {
    var city = getCookie('city');
    if (city != null && city != '') {
      window.location.href = 'http://' + city + '.example.com';
    }
    $('#citygo').change(function() {
      var city = $(this).val();
      window.location.href = 'http://' + city + '.example.com';
    });
  });


  function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
  }

  function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
  }

  function dropCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
  }
  //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: What is this getCookie function? Have you tried alerting or writing the city variable to console.log?

Comment: My goal is to set cookie then redirect. Not sure about the console.log. Can you add the simple code? Thanks.

Comment: I just add some more code so please check the top. Thanks.

Comment: Please, format your code with proper indentation. Flat, unindented code is much more difficult to read. There is a Tidy button in the [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) edit that can help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, cookies are set to only send on the same domain name that they came from. Be sure you set the cookie domain to .example.com to share across all subdomains (assuming that you indeed are trying to share across subdomains). /

```
 $.cookie('city', 'whatevercityhere', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: '.example.com' });
```

Edit: Per comments below, also check that the cookie isn't set to http-only.

Comment: To add to Joe Love's answer you may also want to inspect the cookie for the HTTP-Only Flag. If set to true then Javascript will not be able to read

Comment: Can you please write the code for setting the cookie domain to .example.com to share across all subdomains? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this example:**

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var cookieName = 'HelloWorld';
    var cookieValue = 'HelloWorld';
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
    document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate 
                      + ";domain=.example.com;path=/";
    </script>
```

Comment: Redirected page is unavailable.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var cookieName = 'city';
var cookieValue = 'city';
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
document.cookie = city +"=" + city + ";expires=" + myDate 
                  + ";domain=.listhall.com;path=/";
</script>

Comment: use this mannar document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate + ";domain=.example.com;path=/"; not like document.cookie = city +"=" + city + ";expires=" + myDate + ";domain=.listhall.com;path=/";

Comment: please Check your href in console.log if you got value then change redirect method.